# A Simple but Odd Riley

Tags: riddle, rhyme, acrostic

I have another simple Riley riddle for the community here; good luck to you all!

> Stab at the infix, it’s hidden quite well; fall into aheap, but remove the shell.
>
> Test the prefix for taste, a simple vegan meal; just don’t forget, the end you must peel.
>
> Eat at the suffix, but wash your hands first; it’s time for dinner, go quench your thirst.
>
> All together you’ll find, a word hard to rhyme; you’ll find it don’t worry, all in due time.
>
> Maybe you’re hungry, would you like to join? A dinner for two, on the flip of a coin.

Explain the acrostic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be:

> VEGETABLE

Stab at the infix, it’s hidden quite well; fall into aheap, but remove the shell.

> If you remove the thick two-letter shell of the word "aheap", you get the letter E

Test the prefix for taste, a simple vegan meal; just don’t forget, the end you must peel.

> the prefix of vegan is VEG, also if you "peel" the last two letters, that's what you get.

Eat at the suffix, but wash your hands first; it’s time for dinner, go quench your thirst.

> eat at the TABLE

All together you’ll find, a word hard to rhyme; you’ll find it don’t worry, all in due time.

> I can't think of a rhyme for vegetable... maybe festival?

Maybe you’re hungry, would you like to join? A dinner for two, on the flip of a coin.

> I bet there exists a coin that has a vegetable on one side.  And yes, I would like to join!

Explain the acrostic.

> You can steam vegetables.  And then eat them.  Because they are steamed vegetables.  Yummy!

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> a banana bar?  I hope so, now I'm hungry.  And banana is hard to rhyme with (Fie Fie fofana).

Prefix

> banana - a simple vegan meal.  and remember to peel the right end!

Infix

> you can find "nab" in the bananabar if you remove the space and shell

Suffix

> you can eat at a bar and quench your thirst.

Acrostic

> Steam.  Well, you can steam plantains, which are bananas.  I think you can also make banana bars using steam, but I'm not a cook.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a first timer, so not real sure I'm doing any of this site justice:

I'm guessing based on keywords:

> STEAM, hidden, remove the shell, vegan meal, & peel. -- **Hard Boiled Eggs**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! A good answer but not it. Also, please use spoiler tags >! To hide your answers. :)

Comment: Also when possible explain your thought process so others can either learn from or be inspired by your solution.